# Gson.fromJson takes more time on server than local

Tags: java, json, gson

i have this piece of code running on both local and server

```
candidateResults= gson.fromJson(trimmedInput,CandidateResults.class);
```

time taken to run on local: 19ms

time taken to run on server: 7614 ms.

I have my local system on Windows and server on Linux; with server having the configuration way more than my local.

Also we are running JBOSS on both local and server

Can anyone explain why the same code is taking soo much time on server?
I tried googling but could not find any relevant answers.

Any help would be appreciated !!!
Thankx!!

Comment: Any suggestions guys!!..

Comment: Does the server machine have a lot of other services working at the same time? I'm unmarshalling speed is bound to the cpu speed, or in this case cycles that it is given. In your local machine you're probably only testing the given application but on the server machine you may have many other things working at the same time that take up a lot of your cpu time making gson way slower. There shouldn't be any other difference appart from that.

Comment: @Konstantine there are couple of things running on server, but none of them which are heavy or which consume lot of cycles power second